# Why can i not add an ID to an element using pure javasctipt? setattribute is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an ID to one particular element which all have the same class name this is an example but it won't work on the example here is what i am trying.

```
  <div class = "ABC">
  <p> child </p>
  </div>

 <div class = "ABC">
 <p> child </p>
 </div>

 <div class = "ABC">
 <p> child </p>
 </div>


 <div class = "ABC">
 <p> child </p>
 </div>


 var ref = document.getElementsByClassName("ABC")[3];
 var ref2child = ref.childNodes
 var addID = ref2child.setAttribute("id", "HOV")
```

when i look in the console it says Uncaught TypeError: ref2child.setAttribute is not a function(…)

Comment: Start by looking at the value of `ref2child`. It's not an element. Then you should look for the documentation of `childNodes`.

Comment: i know it's not an element but the variable is referencing the child element i want to target when i type ref2child in the console it returns the element i want

Comment: Are you missing line terminators (;) in the actual code too?

Comment: Did my solution worked to you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ref.childNodes` give you a list of nodes, so you need to tell which by adding an index, like this `ref.childNodes[0]`.

As `ref.childNodes` also return text nodes, a better method would likely be `ref.children`

*Note: The `setAttribute` method doesn't have a return value*

*Note 2: When you run it on your code, make sure the script executes either at the end of the body or in the onload/domready event, or else you will get that error as the element is not yet available.*

```js
var ref = document.getElementsByClassName("ABC")[3];
var ref2child = ref.children[0];
ref2child.setAttribute("id", "HOV");

/* this line is only for demo purpose, showing this method works */
ref2child.innerHTML += ref2child.getAttribute("id");
```

```html
<div class = "ABC">
  <p> child </p>
  </div>

 <div class = "ABC">
 <p> child </p>
 </div>

 <div class = "ABC">
 <p> child </p>
 </div>


 <div class = "ABC">
 <p> child </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: i tried what you said and it says the following  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Comment: @Jake I updated my answer so it shows it works. And btw, the `setAttribute` method doesn't have a return value

Comment: @Jake And when you run it on your code, make sure the script executes either at the end of the body or in onload/domready event, or else you will get that error as the element is not yet available

Comment: ref2child.innerHTML is not required, to set the ID for the element

Comment: @KhaledObaid No, it is merely there to show it **did** change

Answer (score 0):

Yes setAttribute  is not function for the collection of child nodes.

Try this :

```
 var refs = document.getElementsByClassName("ABC");
 var ref2child = refs[0];
 ref2child.setAttribute("id", "HOV")

 // Now this should give you a reference to the item
 var itemWithId = document.getElementById('Hov')
```

Comment: This set the id on the parent element, not its child, which was asked for.

Comment: I think the div item what he is looking for, otherwise adding .firstChild with solve the issue.

Comment: Obviously not ... and the code in the question says the same, the child is the target